# Ruby Regex "Contains"

Tags: regex, ruby

I have the following regex in ruby code that catches all the fields where the field name **is**

> timestamp

What I need to do is to get the fields that **contains** timestamp in their names

Here is the code:

```
event.to_hash.each { |k, v|
                if k =~ /(^|\.)timestamp$/ and v.to_s.to_i == v
                    event.set(k, LogStash::Timestamp.new(Time.at(v/1000)))
                end
            }
```

Comment: Note: `$` is *end-of-line* in Ruby, not *end-of-string* like in other languages. Use `\z` instead for "ends with". Likewise `\A` instead of `^` for *beginning-of-string*.

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Normally I'd use a tool like [`grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) here on the keys as it's ideal for pattern matching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with `.*` and anchors:

```
x = %w(timestamp also_timestamp timestamp_also also_timestamp_here not_time_stamp)
=> [
  "timestamp",
  "also_timestamp",
  "timestamp_also",
  "also_timestamp_here",
  "not_time_stamp"
]

x.each do |y|
  puts "#{y} is timestamp" if y.match?(/\A.*timestamp.*\z/)
end;

timestamp is timestamp
also_timestamp is timestamp
timestamp_also is timestamp
also_timestamp_here is timestamp
```

You can also do it without regex using [String#include](https://ruby-doc.org//core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-include-3F)

Comment: Typo alert: `include?`.

Comment: yup that's correct, sorry for the mistake @CarySwoveland